# how to type at sign (@) in Linux guest operating system

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, backtrack-linux

I have Linux (Backtrack5) running as guest operating system in IOS. 
There seems to be some problems with certain keys, I can't type the @ sign.. instead, it gives 2 (in superscript).

I have tried hex (%40) but it won't compile.
I have reinstalled it with another keyboard layouts but problem reproduces.

Is there a file where i can reconfigure certain keys?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I may sound trivial, but maybe this is your case.
It might be that *the keymap your system loads by default does not match the one your physical keyboard actually has*.
You can change the keyboard layout you're using with

```
setxkbmap it Return
```

typed in a console in your graphical environment (X11), be it under KDE, GNOME, or what you have. With that command you would use an Italian keyboard layout, it looks like the two-letter code for a Danish one is *da*.
If you're not working with a graphical environment you can set your keyboard layout with

```
loadkeys it Return
```